# I2P-zero: floodfill routers

Tags: i2p, i2p-zero

How to know if a particular instance of a router is a floodfill router?

Does it requires special configuration for a router to become a floodfill router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to know if a particular instance of a router is a floodfill router?

There is no user facing functionality exposed in i2p-zero to query the status of a peer to determine if they have floodfill enabled.

> Does it requires special configuration for a router to become a floodfill router?

The configuration setting is `router.floodfillParticipant=true` in the router.config (untested, but should work).